# Shooting a projectile in unity always return null exception

Tags: unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, rigid-bodies, projectile

So I'm currently working on my game project using unity3D and I came across this weird error.

I'm trying to instantiate and shoot a projectile forward. here's my Update code:

```
if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1")){
        Vector3 frontDir = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward * arrowShotForce);

        if (chosenProj){
            Rigidbody shotProj = Instantiate(chosenProj, transform.position, transform.rotation) as Rigidbody;
            shotProj.AddForce(frontDir);
        }
    }
```

when I tried to play the script, it gets error at **shotProj.AddForce(frontDir)** saying 
**NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

I've checked the 'chosenProj' gameobject and have assigned it with a projectile model and I still got this error. the projectile won't fly forward and I feel so dumb because I've worked with unity for a month now

any idea why?

THX b4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code, where you get a `NullReferenceException` in the last line:

```
Rigidbody shotProj = Instantiate(
    chosenProj, transform.position, transform.rotation)
    as Rigidbody;
shotProj.AddForce(frontDir);
```

In the last line something must be `null`, or otherwise you wouldn't get the exception. Since `frontDir` is a `Vector3` value type, the only reference type that can be `null` is `shotProj`.

How could it be `null`? Well, when the return value of `Instantiate()` cannot be cast to a `Rigidbody`, the `as Rigidbody` expression will return `null`.

---

So, I conclude that your `chosenProj` is *not* a `RigidBody`. It is actually a `GameObject` that has a rigid body component on it. To get the `RigidBody`, use this:

```
GameObject shotProj = (GameObject)Instantiate(chosenProj, transform.position, transform.rotation);
shotProj.rigidbody.AddForce(frontDir);
```

[`GameObject` class](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) documentation has more info on how to get components from game objects.

Comment: OMG so that's why it's not working... THX a lot Virtlink, worth a chosen answer....